# Canvas how to animate a height from 0 to the given height.

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

```
     paintForegroundBars(hours: Array<number>) {
        let barColor = "#b3bec9";
        let numBars = hours.length;
        let barWidth = Math.floor((this.canvasWidth / numBars) - this.barsSpacing);
        let maxBarHeight = this.canvasHeight - (this.timesHeight + (this.timesSpacing * 2)); 
        let barLeft = 0 + (this.barsSpacing / 2);

        this.canvasContext.fillStyle = barColor;
        this.canvasContext.strokeStyle = barColor;
        this.canvasContext.lineJoin = "round";
        this.canvasContext.lineWidth = this.cornerRadius;

        for (let i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            let barHeight = Math.round(maxBarHeight * hours[i]);
            if (barHeight > 0) {
                let barTop = maxBarHeight - barHeight;
                let roundedBarTop = barTop + (this.cornerRadius / 2);
                let roundedBarLeft = barLeft + (this.cornerRadius / 2);
                let roundedBarWidth = barWidth - this.cornerRadius;
                let roundedBarHeight = barHeight - this.cornerRadius;

                this.canvasContext.strokeRect(roundedBarLeft, roundedBarTop, roundedBarWidth, roundedBarHeight);
                this.canvasContext.fillRect(roundedBarLeft, roundedBarTop, roundedBarWidth, roundedBarHeight);
            }

            barLeft = Math.floor(barLeft + barWidth) + (this.barsSpacing);
        }

    }
```

At the moment I am drawing the height of a bar chart with the below code:

```
 this.canvasContext.strokeRect(roundedBarLeft, roundedBarTop, roundedBarWidth, roundedBarHeight);
 this.canvasContext.fillRect(roundedBarLeft, roundedBarTop, roundedBarWidth, roundedBarHeight);
```

Instead of when this runs it just being a fixed height I want it to animate from 0 to the height that has been calculated in my JS. How do you go about doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: I would use a library for tweening, like TweenMax https://greensock.com/tweenmax or you can implement your own using requestAnimationFrame and a formula which you can find here http://gizma.com/easing/

Comment: Thanks but a lib isn't great as im doing this as a learning experience to gain knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of how this kind of animation works. The thing you are looking for is the *easing* value - once you have that, you are set! In this case I store the start time inside the `start` variable, and then you simply take the current time, remove the start time and divide it by the time you want to pass. This will give you a number between 0 and 1, and multiplying any other number by that will give you the number in the range 0 to n. If you want to add a base value to this, your general formula is basically this:

```
fromValue + (nowTime - sinceTime) / duration * (toValue - fromValue);
```

The reason the *easing* value is so important is that it allows tweening. For example, you can create a smooth curve by multiplying this easing value by itself:

```
var easing = (nowTime - sinceTime) / duration;
    easing = easing * easing; 
fromValue + easing * (toValue - fromValue);
```

Use a graphing application to learn more about these curves :)

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var start = Date.now();
var duration = 5000;

var animationFrame = false;

canvas.width = 40;
canvas.height = 400;

function drawBar(){
  var progress = (Date.now() - start) / duration;
    if( progress >= 1 ){
      // Final state before stopping any drawing function
      ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      window.cancelAnimationFrame( drawBar );
    } else {
      // In progress
      ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
      ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height * progress );
      window.requestAnimationFrame( drawBar );
    }
}

animationFrame = setInterval( drawBar, 1000 / 60 );

document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ){
  start = Date.now();
  window.cancelAnimationFrame( drawBar );
  window.requestAnimationFrame( drawBar );
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I really don't understand it. What is an easer

Comment: It's not an _easer_ its a _type of number_ - what you are looking for is a number that tells you how much of the animation is complete. The easiest way is to reduce your number to a value between zero and one. At 0 your animation still needs to start, at .5 you are halfway through and so on. Once you have that value, you can use that formula. For example, fi you want it to grow from 100px to 200px, you do `100 + easing * (200 - 100)`. Easing is simply calculated using `(currentTime - startTime) / duration`. I can't make this simpeler...